# Paramiko, opening a SOCKS proxy but from machine B to C

Tags: ssh, paramiko

Working on a remote server that doesn't have access to internet. I have 3 machines, A, `hasinet` and `noinet`. I want to give `noinet` access to internet, I succesfully achieved it thanks to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116867/serve-internet-to-remote-machine-via-ssh-session) link. (For others interested, don't forget to add the right socks config in your `.curlrc` if you don't have sudo).

I'm looking how to automate & pythonize this procedure with Paramiko:

```
machineA$ ssh noinet
noinet$ ssh -D 1080 hasinet
```

Here's what I came up with:

```py
        noinet = paramiko.SSHClient()
        noinet.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        noinet.connect('noinet', port=22, username='XXX', password='YYY')

        noinet_transport = noinet.get_transport()
        noinet_channel = noinet_transport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", ("hasinet",22), ("noinet", 22))

        hasinet = paramiko.SSHClient()
        hasinet.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        hasinet.connect('hasinet', username='XXX', password='YYY', sock=noinet_channel)

        # Opening a tunnel from noinet to hasinet on port 1080
        print("Opening tunnel")
        forward_tunnel(1080,"localhost",1080, hasinet.get_transport())
```

The code doesn't raise any errors, and the original code worked fine when I use only 2 machines. I don't have an SSH server on machine A so I need to serve internet by passing through B, that's why there are 3 machines. If machine B had python I guess it would also be easy (but exposes my password).

The `forward_tunnel` comes from paramiko's demo examples: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/forward.py

The tunnel opens fine, the script doesn't raise any error, but the proxy `localhost:1080` gives a `Connection refused` which means the tunnel is not open.

Comment: *"Isn't working"* isn't working as a problem description.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have no problem in paramiko, the code doesn't raise any errors but localhost:1080 refuses connection on `noinet` which means the tunnel is not opened.